# How do I get a Private Sub to work in conjunction with a "normal" Sub?

Tags: excel, vba, printing, pivot-table

I have a large database of emails from roughly 200 or so companies. I am trying to create individual lists for each company that include all users from that company. The idea is to have a target cell where the company names are looped and then have a pivot table update based on the target cell. The resulting list is printed to PDF.

In the code below, the top section filters through the company names in the target cell and prints each time to PDF.

The code at the bottom filters the pivot table based on the company name in the target cell. This section also works, but ONLY if I am in the worksheet and changing the Company Name on my own ie. without the above macro.

```
Sub UserList_Creation()
'Define Worksheet
Dim wk As Worksheet

Set wk = Worksheets("Users")

'Add +1 to the Lookup Cell
Do
Range("F1").Value = Range("F1").Value + 1


' SavePDF Macro
'

'
ChDir "C:\Users\jhercksen\Desktop\Q2_2019"
wk.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\jhercksen\Desktop\Q2_2019\Inactive Companies\" & Range("B4").Value _
, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

'Loop through last three steps until the below is satisfied
Loop Until Range("F1") >= Range("F2")
End Sub
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell H6 or H7 is touched
If Intersect(Target, Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Variables
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String

'Details for Pivottable location
Set pt = Worksheets("Users").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Company ")
NewCat = Worksheets("Users").Range("B3").Value

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

I want to figure out how to have these two macros work together, so that when the 1st macro changes the company name in the target cell, the 2nd macro filters the pivot table to the correct company email list before printing to PDF.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Move the work going on in the SelectionChange event (leave the Intersect line where it is) into a separate Sub,  and call it from both the SelectionChange event and the first sub

Comment: To call a private sub on a worksheet, best practices is to create a public sub on that worksheet whose only job is to call the private sub.  You call the public sub from outside the sheet, and it passes control to the private sub.

Comment: @RyanB. the exact opposite actually. This "private sub" is an *event handler*, and best practice is to never invoke these procedures manually - they're meant to be invoked by Excel (or MSForms, if on a UserForm), not by user code. Move as much of the code *outside* of event handlers; event handlers should ideally be one-liners that invoke separate (public?) procedures that implement the actual logic that needs to run.

Comment: Yes Mathieu, I agree with that completely.  Thanks for the correction -- I'm afraid I threw in the general case without checking the particulars.  My bad.

Comment: Thanks guys! Played around with the code a bit more; ended up sticking the selection change event work within the top section. Works perfectly now. Appreciate all the comments. JH

Comment: @Jan Nik, if you are using a loop to control the pivot changes and pdf creation, it seems odd that you would also be using worksheet selection change, typically that is related to human interaction.  If you are looking for a way to "kick off" read: invoke the action I suggest you look at other methods. This is why I am writing this comment:  **The idea is to have a target cell where the company names are looped and then have a pivot table update based on the target cell. The resulting list is printed to PDF.** In this instance you do not need an event listener/event handler. (IMHO)